# HTML Range value won't post

Tags: php, html

Very new to PHP, trying to figure out how to post a value from a HTML range element to a separate page.

Here's the range element;

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValueComfort(this.value)" style="height: 40px;" name="rangecomfort" />
 <span id="range-comfort">1</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    function showValueComfort(newValue)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("range-comfort").innerHTML=newValue;
                    }
        </script>
```

Then on the output page for the form when using $_POST["rangecomfort"], I get an undefined index?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not helpful there. You should use `<form action="handler.php">` and handle $_POST["rangecomfort"] in it. All that your javascript do is to change content of `<span>` when you change range value.

Comment: I understand that, I also need to display the value, however, when it is handled through my external form action file, $_POST["rangecomfort"] gives me an "undefined index" error for rangecomfort.

Comment: What about `<form action="handler.php">`? There is no `<form></form>` construction in your example

Comment: It seems that your handler don't get any data from form. Please show full code with `<form>` tags and submit button